# Condensation on Mirror

Tags: conductors, states-of-matter, insulators, condensation

When taking a hot shower I notice that moisture forms on the surface of my mirror. Mirrors are insulators so why does water vapour condense on the mirror? I've seen explanations that state that when the warm water vapour comes into contact with a cooler surface it condenses. However, why is the mirror a cooler surface? It exists in the same room. Hence shouldn't it be in thermal equilibrium?

Furthermore, on a cold morning why does the front windshield only get frosted when the side windows do not? Is this the same principle as the above?

Answer (score 1):

the temperature difference between the air saturated with vapor and a solid surface necessary to trigger condensation is less than one degree. in a room in which you took a hot shower, the mirror will remain slightly cooler than the saturated air/vapor mixture for many minutes- plenty of time for the mirror to get covered with condensation droplets.

IN a cold car, the vapor comes from your breath, which is directed towards the inside of your windshield- and that's where the condensation will first occur.